# Восклицательный и вопросительный знак вокруг кавычек "!"?

Tags: пунктуация

Допускается ли в письме использование восклицательного и вопросительного знаков вокруг кавычек? Приведу пример:

> *С чего бы это он вопил "На помощь, на помощь!"?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Допускается. См. [Справочник. Кавычки и другие знаки](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/136/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8), п.4.

> Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный или
>   восклицательный знак, то тот же самый знак не повторяется после
>   кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям
>   контекста, ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками и после них.
>   Например: Читали ли вы роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?» Ср.: Мы
>   изучаем роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?». Бойцы двинулись в атаку с
>   криком «Вперёд!». Когда был выдвинут лозунг «Вся власть Советам!»?